# How do i increase the size of my tooltip in c++/cli?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, graphics

I want to increase the size of my tooltip as i want to insert an image as background to my tooltip. I am able to apply an image to my tooltip but the problem is the size of the tooltip being small only the upper part of the image is being displayed.

I am displaying image using Graphics Draw Image function. And I want the tooltip to take original size of an image without creating a rectangle as I tried all already.

I don't want to create my own tooltip. Just increase size of existing one.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it!! Just needed to add spaces on the property Tool tip on mytooltip on that control on which tool tip is used.Here i have used tool tip on my buttons.